# Razer mouse not detected since update

Tags: usb, mouse, driver

After I installed the latest Mac update (Big Sur 11.5.2) my Razer Basilisk V2 mouse is no longer being detected. The light in the mouse turns white, but the mouse isn't working.

I have reset SRAM and PRAM, which didn't work. I have installed bootcamp, because I have assumed that this is a software error, and it didn't work there as well. The USB device was detected, not as the Razer device it is, but it was detected. The following error was visible:

```
This device cannot start. (Code 10)
```

I still think, that this is a software problem and that there is some sort of corrupt information on my system. Unfortunately I do not have a second PC or MacBook to test the Razer mouse itself. Connecting my lightning power cable or my iPhone to the USB-Ports works though!

Is there a way to make my mouse work again? Maybe some sort of software or the possibility to remove corrupt files?

Comment: First thing I would check is if Razor have an update for their drivers. Also, what did you update from and was it working correctly then?

Comment: They don't have new updates unfortunately. Also I have updated from the previous version 11.5.1

Comment: Take a look here:  https://manuelreinfurt.medium.com/use-razer-peripherals-on-big-sur-with-razer-synapse-862bded9d484  this site seems to have instructions to fix exactly what you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

Per instructions [found on this site](https://manuelreinfurt.medium.com/use-razer-peripherals-on-big-sur-with-razer-synapse-862bded9d484):

> Boot into recovery mode (Restart your mac and hold ⌘+ R during
> startup. (Command + R)
>
> Go to Utility → Terminal
>
> Type `/usr/sbin/spctl kext-consent add R2H967U8J8` and press Enter
>
> Type `/usr/sbin/spctl kext-consent list` and press Enter

Recommend to visit the site listed above to see full details about what is being done here.